# Передача указателя на метод класса в конструктор вложенного класса

Tags: c++, указатели, конструктор

У меня есть класс, внутри которого объявлен объект другого класса (композиция).
Первый содержит метод, указатель на который нужно передать в конструктор второго класса. Это получилось. Как потом вызвать метод по указателю?
В реальности внутри класса объявляются несколько объектов разных классов. Есть одна функция которую нужно использовать в некоторых из внутренних классов. Поэтому и пытаюсь понять как это сделать. Пробую передать указатель на нее.

заголовочный файл

```
class CharScreen; // класс внутри которого будет объявлен объект Loader
class Loader 
{
    private:
        void (CharScreen::* Conv)(uint8_t index); // указатель на метод
    public:
        Loader(void (CharScreen::* Convertor)(uint8_t index));

        void CalculateMenuSize(); // метод внутри которого нужно сделать 
                                  // вызов, переданного в конструктор 
                                  // метода, по указателю
};

class CharScreen
{
    private:
        Loader Loader; // объявляю объект Loader
    public:
        CharScreen();

        void ConvertVar(uint8_t index); // тот самый метод, который нужно 
                                        // передать в конструктор Loader
};
```

cpp

```
Loader::Loader(void (CharScreen::* Convertor)(uint8_t index)):
{
    Conv = Convertor; // присваиваю объявленному в заголовке указателю, 
                      // преданный в конструктор параметр-указатель на метод
}

void Loader::CalculateMenuSize()
{
    (*Conv)(1); // вот здесь возникает проблема "operand of "*" must be a 
                // pointer"
}

CharScreen::CharScreen():
Loader(&CharScreen::ConvertVar)
{
    Loader.CalculateMenuSize();
}

void CharScreen::ConvertVar(uint8_t index)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Объявление члена класса

```
    Loader Loader;
```

недопустимо. Либо

```
    class Loader Loader;
```

либо сделайте так, чтобы имя поля не совпадало с именем класса. (На самом деле стандарт в этом вопросе как-то неоднозначен...)

---

Ну так а для какого именно объекта класса `CharScreen` вы собрались вызывать этот метод? Нет объекта - нечего и вызывать.

Мое гадание на кофейной гуще подсказывает мне, что вы хотите вызвать этот метод из экземпляра класса `Loader` именно для того объекта `CharScreen`, который содержит в себе этот экземпляр класса `Loader`. В С++ нет готовых инструментов для перехода от содержимого объекта к содержащему объекту. Тут могут помочь "хаки", типа известного `container_of`

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member)\
  ((type *) ((char *) ptr - offsetof(type, member)));

void Loader::CalculateMenuSize()
{
  CharScreen *owner = container_of(this, CharScreen, Loader);
  (owner->*Conv)(1);
}
```

но здесь придется сражаться с правами доступа.

Лучше было бы просто воспользоваться `std::function<>` для хранения "указателя" на метод, а правильный экземпляр такого `std::function<>` формировать в конструирующем коде (при помощи `std::bind` или еще как).

Answer (score 0):

В `CalculateMenuSize` аргументом нужно передать ссылку на объект `CharScreen` если объектов `CharScreen` много экземпляров, чтоб не было недоразумений. Или если он один, тогда метод `ConvertVar` сделайте `static`, тогда можно не использовать конкретный объект.

```
void Loader::CalculateMenuSize(CharScreen & obj) {
    (obj.*Conv)(1); }
```

или

```
class Loader {
  void (*Stat)(uint8_t);};

class CharScreen {
  static void ConvertVar(uint8_t index); };

void Loader::CalculateMenuSize() {
    Stat(1); }
```